# Choices-js keep option in select

Tags: javascript, jquery, choices.js

I am using [Choices.js](https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices) to create a multi select option menu.

In the `<select>` menu it is required to be able to select the same `<option>` multiple times.
This issue has been resolved by using the `addEventListener` function from Choices.js.

**The Issue**

When i want to load the selected options from a **string or ajax** call the `<option>` are only selected one time instead of multiple times.

**For example:** the values `1 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 3` will need to display in the `<select>` menu `ONE - ONE - TWO - THREE - THREE`.

But currently it only shows `ONE - TWO - THREE`.

The issue is that the `addEventListener` is not working when the `setChoiceByValue` is being used.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const query_task = new Choices(document.querySelector('#query_task'), {
    removeItemButton: true,
    maxItemCount: 10,
  });
  query_task.passedElement.element.addEventListener('addItem', function(e) {
    query_task.setChoices([{
      value: e.detail.value,
      label: e.detail.label
    }, ], 'value', 'label', false, );
  }, false, );

  $(document).on('click', '.ajax_data', function() {
    let data = '1,1,2,3,3';
    query_task.removeActiveItems();
    query_task.setChoiceByValue(data.split(','));
    console.log('Ajax data loaded');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://choices-js.github.io/Choices/assets/styles/choices.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/choices.js/9.1.0/choices.min.js"></script>

<div class="row pt-2 px-5">
    <div class="col-12 px-5">
        <label for="query_task" class="form-label">SELECT TASKS</label>
        <select id="query_task" class="form-control choices-multiple" multiple>
            <option value="0">ZERO</option>
            <option value="1">ONE</option>
            <option value="2">TWO</option>
            <option value="3">THREE</option>
            <option value="4">FOUR</option>
        </select>
    <div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="ajax_data btn btn-primary">Load AJAX data</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Solved - Solution:**

```js
let query_data = [
  { value: "0", label: "ZERO" },
  { value: "1", label: "ONE" },
  { value: "2", label: "TWO" },
  { value: "3", label: "THREE" },
  { value: "4", label: "FOUR" }
];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const query_task = new Choices(document.querySelector('#query_task'), {
    removeItemButton: true,
    maxItemCount: 10,
    choices: query_data
  });
  query_task.passedElement.element.addEventListener('addItem', () => reset(), false);
  query_task.passedElement.element.addEventListener('removeItem', () => reset(), false);

  function reset() {
    query_task.clearChoices();
    query_task.setChoices(query_data, "value", "label", false);
  }

  $(document).on('click', '.ajax_data', function() {
    query_task.removeActiveItems();
    let data = '1,1,2,3,3';
    let selected_values = data.split(',')
    $.each(selected_values, function(key, value) {
      query_task.setChoiceByValue(value);
      reset();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://choices-js.github.io/Choices/assets/styles/choices.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/choices.js/9.1.0/choices.min.js"></script>

<div class="row pt-2 px-5">
  <div class="col-12 px-5">
    <label for="query_task" class="form-label">SELECT TASKS</label>
    <select id="query_task" class="form-control choices-multiple" multiple>
    </select>
    <div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="ajax_data btn btn-primary">Load AJAX data</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is bit confusing . There are two issues to fix:

- To add duplicates you need to use [setValue(items)](https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices#setvalueitems) method. Next point explains how to get rid of duplicates.
- After you unselect an item it gets added back to the options list. This creates duplicate items. I couldn't find method to remove a single choice from options list. So as a workaround I am resetting entire options list.

Demo:

```js
let labels = ['ZERO', 'ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR'];
let query_task = null;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  query_task = new Choices(document.querySelector('#query_task'), {
    removeItemButton: true,
    maxItemCount: 10,
    duplicateItemsAllowed: true,
    choices: defaults()
  });

  query_task.passedElement.element.addEventListener('addItem', function(e) {
    query_task.setChoices([{
      value: e.detail.value,
      label: e.detail.label
    }, ], 'value', 'label', false);
  }, false);

  query_task.passedElement.element.addEventListener('removeItem', () => reset(), false);

  $(document).on('click', '.ajax_data', function() {
    let data = '1,1,2,3,3';
    query_task.removeActiveItems();
    query_task.setValue(data.split(',').map((v) => ({value: v, label: labels[+v]})));

    reset();
    console.log('Ajax data loaded');
  });
});

function defaults() {
  return labels.map((lbl, i) => ({value: i, label: lbl}));
}

function reset() {
  query_task.clearChoices();
  query_task.setChoices(defaults(), 'value', 'label', false);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://choices-js.github.io/Choices/assets/styles/choices.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/choices.js/9.1.0/choices.min.js"></script>

<div class="row pt-2 px-5">
  <div class="col-12 px-5">
    <label for="query_task" class="form-label">SELECT TASKS</label>
    <select id="query_task" class="form-control choices-multiple" multiple></select>
    <div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="ajax_data btn btn-primary">Load AJAX data</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using your code we can also call the `reset()` function on `additem` : `query_task.passedElement.element.addEventListener('addItem', () => reset(), false);`. furthermore the value of `duplicateItemsAllowed` is by default set to `true` so there is no point for a declare. Your code pointed me to the possibility to use `query_task.setChoiceByValue(value); ` in a `$.each` loop to select a value followed by `reset()`. Your answer was not 100% what i searched but it pointed me in the correct direction therefor i will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hi [@Crezzur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3877838/crezzur),

Thanks for posting the question, I got to know this tiny yet useful library.(I am definitely using this in my next project)

I did some digging and it seems you can not use setChoicesByValue() for your requirement due to a check in the [library reference code:here](https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices/blob/eb22895f00520af0df49e1c13e0240f87b3a0dad/public/assets/scripts/choices.js#L2460)

However I achieved it by using setValue() instead. Here is a [working stackblitz link for you](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-dkk5kc?devtoolsheight=33&file=script.js)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem of `setValue` is that it will be added to the select list and causes to create multiple duplicates in the select list. Therefor i cannot accept this as an answer.